# is there a way to append different things into div with a counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var play = function(){
var counter = 0;
if(counter == 0){
  $( this ).click(function(e) {
   var targetBox = (e.target.id);
   $("#" + targetBox).append("something");
   counter++;
 })
} else if (counter == 1){
  $( this ).click(function(e) {
   var targetBox = (e.target.id);
   $("#" + targetBox).append("O");
   counter--;
  });
 }
}
```

I'm trying to make a button that changes whats appended to my `targetBox` with a counter. If the counter is 1 append something then if the counter is 0 append something else. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $( this ).click(function(e) {
   var targetBox = (e.target.id);
   if(counter == 0) {
     $("#" + targetBox).append("something");
     counter++;
   } else if(counter == 1){
     $("#" + targetBox).append("O");
     counter--;
   }
 })
```

Answer (score 3):

Move condition i.e. *if block* inside the click handler.

```
var play = function() {

    var counter = 0;

    //Use proper selector here
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        var targetBox = (e.target.id);
        if (counter == 0) {
            counter++;
            $("#" + targetBox).append("something");

        } else if (counter == 1) {
            counter--;
            $("#" + targetBox).append(O);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the condition inside the event handler:

```
$(this).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetBox = e.target.id;
    if( counter == 0 ) {
        $("#" + targetBox).append( "something" );
        counter++;
    }
    else {
        $("#" + targetBox).append( "O" );
        counter--;
    }
});
```